# Horizontal Bar Plot in Plotly using Cufflinks with 2 traces

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I have a pandas DataFrame `ten_day` that looks like this:

```
XLF US Equity           NaN
PEO PW Equity     -2.797857
GLE FP Equity      4.497489
CBK GY Equity      6.162684
BAC US Equity           NaN
UCG IM Equity      4.250801
ITRXESE Index     -0.996103
HSBC US Equity          NaN
RBS LN Equity     -1.347926
CABK SM Equity     8.127579
SAN SM Equity      4.521443
ISP IM Equity      5.023080
SX7E Index         4.900426
ANZ AU Equity      0.723205
CSGN VX Equity    -0.800900
SWEDA SS Equity   -0.973182
POP SM Equity      4.434381
BNP FP Equity      3.378214
BARC LN Equity    -0.066818
Name: Vol_Adj_10, dtype: float64
```

I have created a plot in Plotly (https://plot.ly/~dpsugasa/289/_10-day-volatility-adjusted-returns/) using the following code:

```
ten_day.iplot(kind='barh', bargap=.2, filename = 'Vol_Adjusted/Bank Returns/10Day_Vol_Adjusted',\
          title='10 Day Volatility Adjusted Returns', legend = True,
          xTitle = '10D Vol Adjusted Return (30D)', vline ={'x':'0','color':'black','width':'2'}, sortbars=True,
          margin = (200,5))
```

I would like the negative bars to be a different color than the positive bars. Is there a way to do this using only cufflinks?

I've considered using `ten_day.loc[lambda df: df>0]` to filter positive and negative values and then trying to plot two different traces but I am struggling to get the syntax right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `cufflinks` we can just pass a list of colors to the bar chart

```
bar = plotly.graph_objs.Bar(y=df[3], marker=dict(color=np.where(df[3] > 0, 'green', 'red').tolist()))
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=[bar])
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

but `cufflinks` seems to ignore such a list. So we need to pass two different columns with two different colors.

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(pos=df[df[3] > 0][3], 
                  neg=df[df[3] <= 0][3])).iplot(kind='barh',  
                                                colors=dict(pos='green', 
                                                            neg='red')
                                               )
```

[image]

---

**Complete code**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import cufflinks
import io
import numpy as np

cufflinks.go_offline()
txt = """XLF US Equity           NaN
PEO PW Equity     -2.797857
GLE FP Equity      4.497489
CBK GY Equity      6.162684
BAC US Equity           NaN
UCG IM Equity      4.250801
ITRXESE Index     -0.996103
HSBC US Equity          NaN
RBS LN Equity     -1.347926
CABK SM Equity     8.127579
SAN SM Equity      4.521443
ISP IM Equity      5.023080
SX7E Index         4.900426
ANZ AU Equity      0.723205
CSGN VX Equity    -0.800900
SWEDA SS Equity   -0.973182
POP SM Equity      4.434381
BNP FP Equity      3.378214
BARC LN Equity    -0.066818"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
bar = plotly.graph_objs.Bar(y=df[3], marker=dict(color=np.where(df[3] > 0, 'green', 'red').tolist()))
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=[bar])
plotly.offline.plot(fig)

pd.DataFrame(dict(pos=df[df[3] > 0][3], 
                  neg=df[df[3] <= 0][3])).iplot(kind='barh', 
                                                bargap=.2, 
                                                filename='Vol_Adjusted/Bank Returns/10Day_Vol_Adjusted',\
                                                title='10 Day Volatility Adjusted Returns', 
                                                legend = True,
                                                xTitle='10D Vol Adjusted Return (30D)', 
                                                margin=(200,5), 
                                                colors=dict(pos='green', 
                                                            neg='red')
                                               )
```

Comment: thanks it looks like it should work but I am struggling to even create the DataFrame that you created. I get the error `TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`

Comment: Are you using Python3.# or Python2.7?

Comment: @dsugasa If you are on Python2.7 add `u` before the quotation marks